# Extract deeply nested properties into array of unique values

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Considering the below JSON is my object, how can i extract userId and roles, store them in separate arrays respectively, without having any duplicate values.

```
let rosterInfo = 
    [
        {
           "shiftName": "A",
            "userDetail": [
            {
              "userId": 'Mary',
              "roles": ['Operator', 'Supervisor']
            },
            {
              "userId": 'John',
              "roles": ['Supervisor', Maintenance Technician]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
           "shiftName": "B",
          "userDetail": [
            {
              "userId": 'Crusier',
              "roles": ['Operator', 'Supervisor']
            },
            {
              "userId": 'Philips',
              "roles": ['Operator', 'Supervisor']
            }
          ]
        },
        {
           "shiftName": "C",
             "userDetail": [
            {
              "userId": 'Heath',
              "roles": ['Operator', 'Supervisor']
            },
            {
              "userId": 'Daniel',
              "roles": ['Operator', 'Supervisor']
            }
          ]
        }
    ];
```

Final Array of roles should be: ['Operator, 'Supervisor', 'Maintenance technician']
Final Array of userId should be: ['Heath', 'Daniel', 'Philips', 'John', 'Mary', 'Crusier']

Note: I have used ForEach and For loops, but that will not be an ideal solution. Here is my solution using loops.

```
  rosterInfo.forEach(rosterItem => {
  for (let userItem of rosterItem['userDetail']) {
    userItem['roles'].forEach(role => {
      this.rolesInAShift.indexOf(role) > -1
        ? ''
        : this.rolesInAShift.push(role);
    });
  }
});
```

In addition to that if at all from the given above Object, If at all i want to filter above object with name, "John" and of role "Supervisor", and the final would be something of this kind.

```
rosterInfo = 
    [
        {
           "shiftName": "A",
            "userDetail": [
            {
              "userId": 'John',
              "roles": ['Supervisor', 'Maintenance Technician']
            }

          ]
        },
        {
           "shiftName": "B",
          "userDetail": [

          ]
        },
        {
           "shiftName": "C",
             "userDetail": [

          ]
        }
    ]
```

I was able to achieve this using loops, however using below logic,doesn't get what I want.

```
 someVar = rosterInfo.map(element => {
        return {
          ...element,
          userDetail: element.userDetail.filter(
            subElement =>
              subElement.roles.indexOf('Supervisor') > -1 &&
              subElement.userId.indexOf('Rajasekhar')
          )
        };
      });
```

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Array of roles should be: ['Operator, 'Supervisor', 'Maintenance technician'] 
 Array of userId should be: ['Heath', 'Daniel', 'Philips', 'John', 'Mary', 'Crusier']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/map) along with [`Set()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove duplicates:

```js
const rosterInfo = 
    [{"shiftName":"A","userDetail":[{"userId":'Mary',"roles":['Operator','Supervisor']},{"userId":'John',"roles":['Supervisor','Maintenance Technician']}]},{"shiftName":"B","userDetail":[{"userId":'Crusier',"roles":['Operator','Supervisor']},{"userId":'Philips',"roles":['Operator','Supervisor']}]},{"shiftName":"C","userDetail":[{"userId":'Heath',"roles":['Operator','Supervisor']},{"userId":'Daniel',"roles":['Operator','Supervisor']}]}],
    
    userIds = [...new Set(
      rosterInfo
        .map(({userDetail}) =>
          userDetail.map(({userId}) => userId))
        .flat()
    )],
    
    roles = [...new Set(
      rosterInfo
        .map(({userDetail}) => 
          userDetail.map(({roles}) => roles))
        .flat(2)
    )]
    
console.log(userIds)
console.log(roles)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Hi @Yevgen Gorbunkov, Your solution worked for me, I have updated the question, can you please have a look.

Comment: @SatyaRam : Look up through your source array for a match (by 2 criteria - name and role) is totally different subject. I would recommend not to mix the two. Post it as a separate question and I will gladly look into that too.

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce` and `Set` can be done easily. Reduce to loop, Set for unique. Please check the sample.

```js
let rosterInfo = [
  {
    shiftName: "A",
    userDetail: [
      { userId: "Mary", roles: ["Operator", "Supervisor"] },
      { userId: "John", roles: ["Supervisor", "Maintenance Technician"] }
    ]
  },
  {
    shiftName: "B",
    userDetail: [
      { userId: "Crusier", roles: ["Operator", "Supervisor"] },
      { userId: "Philips", roles: ["Operator", "Supervisor"] }
    ]
  },
  {
    shiftName: "C",
    userDetail: [
      { userId: "Heath", roles: ["Operator", "Supervisor"] },
      { userId: "Daniel", roles: ["Operator", "Supervisor"] }
    ]
  }
];
const [roles, names] = rosterInfo.reduce(
  ([roles, names], i) => {
    i.userDetail.forEach(x => {
      roles = roles.concat(x.roles);
      names.push(x.userId);
    });
    return [roles, names];
  },
  [[], []]
);
console.log(Array.from(new Set(roles)), Array.from(new Set(names)));
```